# \hypersetup command from hyperref package not working with auto-pst-pdf

Tags: hyperref, auto-pst-pdf

I need to use the `auto-pst-pdf` package in a large class file of my own. I've found out that, under `pdfLaTeX`, the following MWE compiles to a pdf that does not include the metadata provided by the `\hypersetup` command, whereas if I comment out the `auto-pst-pdf` package load, the metadata fields are set straight. The pdf viewers I've tried with are SumatraPDF 2.3.2 and Adobe Reader XI.

I'm pdfLaTeXing on MikTeX 2.9 over Windows Xp.

Any clue on what's going on?

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage[off]{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup
  {
    pdfinfo =
     {
       Author = {The Author},
       Title = {The Title},
       Subject = {The Subject},
     }
  }

\begin{document}
Just an MWE.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just tried your example and it's no issue with TeXLive 2014 on Linux, regardless whether `auto-pst-pdf` is enabled or not. Seems to be only a problem on MikTeX

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit in to the question the `File list` you get in your `.log`.

Comment: Works fine for me with a current miktex and adobe reader XI.